# Use own __str__() method instead of model's through which object was accessed in Django

Tags: python, django, class, django-models

I have such models:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    pass


class Place(Location):
    name = models.CharField(...)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class Coordinates(Location):
    x = models.DecimalField(...)
    y = models.DecimalField(...)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"({x}, {y})"
```

If I try to query `Location.objects.get(pk=1).__str__()`, I get `Location object (1)`, instead I expect `(123, 456)`.

How can I make objects to use their own `__str__()` method, instead of model's through which I've accessed the object?

Comment: No Django does not by default checks the all subclasses and "specializes" the type, that would be quite inefficient. There are packages like `django-polymorphic` that automatically downcast, but if there are a lot of subclasses, that makes it quite inefficient: https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I try to query `Location.objects.get(pk=1)`, I get `<Location object (1)>`, instead I expect `(123, 456)`.

Django does not automatically downcast, likely for performance reasons: it would mean it has to make `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s to the tables of both `Place` and `Coordinates`, to see which one it is, and then do some magic to create a `Coordinate` model instead. As the number of subclasses grows (including grandchildren, etc.), the amount of `JOIN`s will become huge, with a severe performance penalty.

If you really want this, there are packages like [**`django-polymorphic`** <sup>[readthedocs]</sup>](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) that implement the flow described above, but in general relational databases are just not good with inheritance, and therefore model inheritance is often not a good idea anyway.